# Artifact File spec build parameter containing wildcards fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am writing a Jenkinsfile to get a build from Artifactory, so I an downloading the build using File specs. The problem is that for this project the build parameter changes per release

```
release v1.8.1 -> appName.build.release::v1.0.0
release v2.0.0 -> appName.build.hf.release::v2.0.0
```

I tried to use a regex in order to get the latest build

```
{
    "pattern": "my_artifactory_repo/apps/appName/*/*/*.exe",
    "build": "appName.build*release*/LATEST",
    "target": "target_path",
    "flat": "true"
},
```

But this caused a fail to download such release

```
expected to call org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.ArtifactoryServer.download but wound up catching artifactoryDownload
```

Why does the "build" parameter does not accept the wildcard? What is the practical solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to use artifact python module. I wrote a python script called from the Jenkinsfile to solve the problem.

```
pip install artifactory
```